# The word "Table of content" has been removed when using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xepersian

According to [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304878/) the word "Table of content"(in persian"فهرست"), has been removed. I want it back.
What can I do?

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[]{titlesec} 
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{black}
\makeatletter
\let\oldl@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\oldl@chapter{#1}{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{ #2}}}

\let\old@dottedcontentsline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\old@dottedcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#5}}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {\filleft\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\chaptertitlename\hspace*{2mm}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.6ex]current bounding box.center)}]
    \node[fill=yourcolor,circle,text=white] {\rl{\thechapter}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule[1.5pt]\vspace*{5ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape}
  []

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\vspace*{5ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape}
  []

%command to print the acutal minitoc
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{%
    \noindent\hspace{-2cm}%
    \colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{white}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rounded corners,align=left,fill=yourcolor, blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}, inner sep=5mm]{%
        \color{white}%
        \begin{minipage}{8cm}%minipage trick
        \begin{RTL}
        \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
        \end{RTL}
        \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\rl{فصل اول}}
\startcontents[chapters]
%print minitoc
\printmyminitoc



\section{سکشن اول}
\lipsum[1]
\section{سکشن دوم}
\section{تست}
\section{الف ب پ}
\lipsum
\chapter{\rl{فصل دوم}}
\end{document}
```

it should be like below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think `titlesec` overwrite the `contentsname` you can restore it with

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\rl{فهرست}}
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[]{titlesec} 
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{black}
\makeatletter
\let\oldl@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\oldl@chapter{#1}{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{ #2}}}

\let\old@dottedcontentsline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\old@dottedcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#5}}}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\rl{فهرست}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {\filleft\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\chaptertitlename\hspace*{2mm}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.6ex]current bounding box.center)}]
    \node[fill=yourcolor,circle,text=white] {\rl{\thechapter}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule[1.5pt]\vspace*{5ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape}
  []



\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\vspace*{5ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape}
  []

%command to print the acutal minitoc
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{%
    \noindent\hspace{-2cm}%
    \colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{white}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rounded corners,align=left,fill=yourcolor, blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}, inner sep=5mm]{%
        \color{white}%
        \begin{minipage}{8cm}%minipage trick
        \begin{RTL}
        \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
        \end{RTL}
        \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\rl{فصل اول}}
\startcontents[chapters]
%print minitoc
\printmyminitoc



\section{سکشن اول}
\lipsum[1]
\section{سکشن دوم}
\section{تست}
\section{الف ب پ}
\lipsum
\chapter{\rl{فصل دوم}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this site](http://qa.parsilatex.com/18239/), `/sffamily` is problem.

By removing it we can restore the word.

Tanks to [Vahid Damanafshan](http://qa.parsilatex.com/user/%D9%88%D8%AD%DB%8C%D8%AF+%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%86%E2%80%8C%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%86)