# How to show Mini table only sections in a chapter not other chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents

I follow that link: [Mini table of contents inside TikZ node on chapter start page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/mini-table-of-contents-inside-tikz-node-on-chapter-start-page)? But I just want to show only sections of The chapter 1 or chapter 2 ... How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[13pt,twoside]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,newlfont,graphicx,multicol,vntex,amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,pgf,tikz,wrapfig,tabvar,url,perpage,fancybox,subcaption,lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[]{titlesec} 
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}

\colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{black}
\makeatletter
\let\oldl@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\oldl@chapter{#1}{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#2}}}

\let\old@dottedcontentsline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\old@dottedcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#5}}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {\filleft\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\chaptertitlename\hspace*{2mm}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.6ex]current bounding box.center)}]
    \node[fill=yourcolor,circle,text=white] {\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule[1.5pt]\vspace*{2ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape}
  []

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\vspace*{5ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape}
  []

%command to print the acutal minitoc
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} 
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \noindent%
    \colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{white}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rounded corners,align=left,fill=yourcolor, blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}, inner sep=5mm]{%
        \color{white}%
        \begin{minipage}{8cm}%minipage trick
        \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
        \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}        

\usepackage[margin=17mm,paperwidth=155mm,paperheight=235mm]{geometry}

%---------------------------------DINH DANG HEADER--------------------------------%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{PPGT qua các kỳ Olympic} % predefined ()
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.75cm} % Thut vao dau don doan van
%\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % Tao bookmark cho sach
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\normalsize
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\startcontents[chapters]
\chapter{TƯ DUY THUẬT TOÁN  VÀ TƯ DUY CÔNG THỨC}
\begin{flushright}
\large {\textbf{Trần Nam Dũng} \footnote{Trường Đại học Khoa Học Tự Nhiên thành phố Hồ Chí Minh.}}\par\nobreak
\vspace*{1cm}
\end{flushright}
\printmyminitoc

\section{Mở đầu}
\noindent
Trong Hội thảo các chuyên đề bồi dưỡng học sinh giỏi toán duyên hải Trung bộ và Tây nguyên lần thứ tư tại Pleiku hôm 19/4 vừa qua, giáo sư Phạm Huy Điển có nêu một vấn đề hết sức thú vị "Trong giảng dạy toán ở các cấp của ta thường chú ý nhiều đến Tư duy công thức.

\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{Câu chuyện về phương trình đa thức}
\noindent
Thực tế thì không hẳn là trong chương trình của ta không đề cập đến tư duy thuật toán. Nhưng quả là càng lên các bậc học cao hơn, tư duy thuật toán càng bị lãng quên, thay vào đó là tư duy công thức máy móc. \medskip




\section{Thuật toán và công thức.}
\noindent
Trước khi tiếp tục câu chuyện về tư duy thuật toán và tư duy công thức, ta hãy nói đôi điều về sự khác biệt giữa thuật toán và công thức. Thuật toán trong nghĩa chung nhất của nó là con đường để đạt được mục đích mong muốn. Công thức là đơn thuốc hay thành phần.

Chứng minh rằng đồ thị liên thông $G$ có chu trình Euler khi và chỉ khi bậc của tất cả các đỉnh của $G$ đều chẵn.
\section{Câu chuyện về phương trình đa thức}
\noindent
Thực tế thì không hẳn là trong chương trình của ta không đề cập đến tư duy thuật toán. Nhưng quả là càng lên các bậc học cao hơn, tư duy thuật toán càng bị lãng quên, thay vào đó là tư duy công thức máy móc. \medskip
\section{Câu chuyện về phương trình đa thức}
\noindent
Thực tế thì không hẳn là trong chương trình của ta không đề cập đến tư duy thuật toán. Nhưng quả là càng lên các bậc học cao hơn, tư duy thuật toán càng bị lãng quên, thay vào đó là tư duy công thức máy móc. \medskip

\chapter{TOÁN HỌC VÀ THUẬT TOÁN}
\printmyminitoc

\section{Toán Học Và Thuật Toán}

Thế còn thuật toán để giải quyết vấn đề visa\index{Visa} thì sao? Với hộ chiếu công vụ, thì tôi không thể đi Pháp. Như vậy tôi phải thay hộ chiếu.
\section{Toán Học Và Thuật Toán}

Thế còn thuật toán để giải quyết vấn đề visa\index{Visa} thì sao? Với hộ chiếu công vụ, thì tôi không thể đi Pháp. Như vậy tôi phải thay hộ chiếu.
\section{Toán Học Và Thuật Toán}

Thế còn thuật toán để giải quyết vấn đề visa\index{Visa} thì sao? Với hộ chiếu công vụ, thì tôi không thể đi Pháp. Như vậy tôi phải thay hộ chiếu.

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of my chapter]

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand your question. Do you want to have only Chapter 1 und Chapter 2 to be minitoced and chapter 3 should not be used or do you only want to have sections but no subsection?

Comment: @touhami is completed my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution

1. `hyperref` after `titletoc`
2. `\startcontents[chapters]` add in `\printmyminitoc` to stop preview toc and start the new one.

---

**complete code**

```
\documentclass[13pt,twoside]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,newlfont,graphicx,multicol,vntex,amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,pgf,tikz,wrapfig,tabvar,url,perpage,fancybox,subcaption,lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[]{titlesec} 
\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{008bb2}

\colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{black}
\makeatletter
\let\oldl@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\oldl@chapter{#1}{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#2}}}

\let\old@dottedcontentsline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\old@dottedcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#5}}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {\filleft\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\chaptertitlename\hspace*{2mm}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.6ex]current bounding box.center)}]
    \node[fill=yourcolor,circle,text=white] {\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule[1.5pt]\vspace*{2ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape}
  []

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\color{yourcolor}}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\vspace*{5ex}\huge\sffamily\itshape}
  []

%command to print the acutal minitoc
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} 
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \noindent%
    \colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{white}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rounded corners,align=left,fill=yourcolor, blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}, inner sep=5mm]{%
        \color{white}%
        \begin{minipage}{8cm}%minipage trick     
\startcontents[chapters]\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
        \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}        

\usepackage[margin=17mm,paperwidth=155mm,paperheight=235mm]{geometry}

%---------------------------------DINH DANG HEADER--------------------------------%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{PPGT qua các kỳ Olympic} % predefined ()
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.75cm} % Thut vao dau don doan van
%\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % Tao bookmark cho sach
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\normalsize
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{TƯ DUY THUẬT TOÁN  VÀ TƯ DUY CÔNG THỨC}
\begin{flushright}
\large {\textbf{Trần Nam Dũng} \footnote{Trường Đại học Khoa Học Tự Nhiên thành phố Hồ Chí Minh.}}\par\nobreak
\vspace*{1cm}
\end{flushright}
\printmyminitoc

\section{Mở đầu}
\noindent
Trong Hội thảo các chuyên đề bồi dưỡng học sinh giỏi toán duyên hải Trung bộ và Tây nguyên lần thứ tư tại Pleiku hôm 19/4 vừa qua, giáo sư Phạm Huy Điển có nêu một vấn đề hết sức thú vị "Trong giảng dạy toán ở các cấp của ta thường chú ý nhiều đến Tư duy công thức.

\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{Câu chuyện về phương trình đa thức}
\noindent
Thực tế thì không hẳn là trong chương trình của ta không đề cập đến tư duy thuật toán. Nhưng quả là càng lên các bậc học cao hơn, tư duy thuật toán càng bị lãng quên, thay vào đó là tư duy công thức máy móc. \medskip




\section{Thuật toán và công thức.}
\noindent
Trước khi tiếp tục câu chuyện về tư duy thuật toán và tư duy công thức, ta hãy nói đôi điều về sự khác biệt giữa thuật toán và công thức. Thuật toán trong nghĩa chung nhất của nó là con đường để đạt được mục đích mong muốn. Công thức là đơn thuốc hay thành phần.

Chứng minh rằng đồ thị liên thông $G$ có chu trình Euler khi và chỉ khi bậc của tất cả các đỉnh của $G$ đều chẵn.
\section{Câu chuyện về phương trình đa thức}
\noindent
Thực tế thì không hẳn là trong chương trình của ta không đề cập đến tư duy thuật toán. Nhưng quả là càng lên các bậc học cao hơn, tư duy thuật toán càng bị lãng quên, thay vào đó là tư duy công thức máy móc. \medskip
\section{Câu chuyện về phương trình đa thức}
\noindent
Thực tế thì không hẳn là trong chương trình của ta không đề cập đến tư duy thuật toán. Nhưng quả là càng lên các bậc học cao hơn, tư duy thuật toán càng bị lãng quên, thay vào đó là tư duy công thức máy móc. \medskip

\chapter{TOÁN HỌC VÀ THUẬT TOÁN}
\printmyminitoc

\section{Toán Học Và Thuật Toán}

Thế còn thuật toán để giải quyết vấn đề visa\index{Visa} thì sao? Với hộ chiếu công vụ, thì tôi không thể đi Pháp. Như vậy tôi phải thay hộ chiếu.
\section{Toán Học Và Thuật Toán}

Thế còn thuật toán để giải quyết vấn đề visa\index{Visa} thì sao? Với hộ chiếu công vụ, thì tôi không thể đi Pháp. Như vậy tôi phải thay hộ chiếu.
\section{Toán Học Và Thuật Toán}

Thế còn thuật toán để giải quyết vấn đề visa\index{Visa} thì sao? Với hộ chiếu công vụ, thì tôi không thể đi Pháp. Như vậy tôi phải thay hộ chiếu.

\end{document}
```