# Help with Mini table of contents inside TikZ node on chapter start page

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, report

[Mini table of contents inside TikZ node on chapter start page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/mini-table-of-contents-inside-tikz-node-on-chapter-start-page)

Hiya, this is a question regarding the above question and solution. I was hoping someone could assist me with an error I am getting (no doubt due to my technical ineptitude).

When I have more than one chapter, it prints sections from prior and future chapters in plain text format below or above the mini table of contents. I've attached a photo as an example.

Below is the code I have used.

If anyone can help, I would be ever so grateful!

```
[![%\documentclass\[a4paper\]{report}
\documentclass\[a4paper\]{report}

\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images such as the example fish picture
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}} %Setting the graphicspath
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\usepackage\[natbibapa\]{apacite}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{clrscode}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage\[absolute\]{textpos} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

%%%% allows you to manually change chapter number for submissions
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%% allows you to have sections start as 1 instead of 1.1
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
%This is for The mini table of contents
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage\[\]{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}

\definecolor{yourcolor}{HTML}{D3D3D3}

\colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{black}
\makeatletter
\let\oldl@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\oldl@chapter{#1}{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#2}}}

\let\old@dottedcontentsline\@dottedtocline
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\old@dottedcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{{\textcolor{chpnumbercolor}{#5}}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}\[display\]
  {\normalfont\color{black}}
  {\filleft\Huge\rmfamily\bfseries\chaptertitlename\hspace*{2mm}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}\[baseline={(\[yshift=-.6ex\]current bounding box.center)}\]
    \node\[fill=black,circle,text=white\] {\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\[1.5pt\]\vspace*{5ex}\huge\rmfamily\itshape}
  \[\]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}\[display\]
  {\normalfont\color{black}}
  {}
  {1ex}
  {\vspace*{5ex}\huge\rmfamily\itshape}
  \[\]

%command to print the acutal minitoc
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{%
    \noindent\hspace{0cm}%
    \colorlet{chpnumbercolor}{black}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node\[rounded corners=0,align=left,fill=white, inner sep=4mm\]{%
        \color{black}%
        \begin{minipage}{11cm}%minipage trick
        \printcontents\[chapters\]{}{1}{}%this last piece \vspace{-8pt}\hspace{-2000pt} is to remove the weird chapter.# heading. Could not figure out any other way!
        \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    


\begin{document}


\chapter{Contextualizing rhythm in Stockholm}\label{chapter_rhythm}
\startcontents\[chapters\]
%print minitoc
{\setstretch{1.0}
\begin{scriptsize}
\printmyminitoc
\end{scriptsize}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%  RHYTHM IN STOCKHOLM
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Introduction: Rhythm in Stockholm}

In this chapter, I demonstrate that low rhythmic alternation is a feature in Stockholm's multiethnolect. I also provide data that shows that rhythmic alternation is stylistically sensitive; alternation increases with formality for speakers of multiethnolect. I define rhythm as the alternation of strong and weak elements and operationalize it using the \textit{normalized pairwise variability index of vowels} (\textit{nPVI-V}) \citep{lowetal2000}. I also show that high alternation is a feature of Stockholm's white \textit{svensk} working class and that this too is stylistically sensitive; alternation decreases with formality for working-class \textit{svensk} speakers. Independent of other social factors, younger speakers have lower prosodic alternation than older speakers. I interpret this to mean that low alternation is diffusing into mainstream Stockholm speech.

\subsection{Blah}
\section{Blah}

\subsection{Blah}
\section{Blah}
\subsection{Blah}

\chapter{Rhythm in Stockholm's vernacular}\label{chapter_rhythm}
\startcontents\[chapters\]
%print minitoc
{\setstretch{1.0}
\begin{scriptsize}
\printmyminitoc
\end{scriptsize}
}

\subsection{Blah}
\section{Blah}

\subsection{Blah}
\section{Blah}
\subsection{Blah}


\end{document}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! It is a good practice to remove irrelevant packages. Not only it helps us but it helps you learn how packages interact and how to debug. For instance, you include `setspace` twice.