# How do I recreate this two-column TOC layout with chapter goals on the left and TOC on the right

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, titletoc, minitoc, etoc

Recently I have been looking through Till Tantau's (the creator of Ti*k*Z) script on logic (see [here](https://www.tcs.uni-luebeck.de/de/mitarbeiter/tantau/lehre/lectures/Logik-2017.pdf)).

He uses a beautiful layout at each beginning of a chapter.

[image]

So I want to recreate the little "table", where learning goals ("Lernziele") are on the left half and the TOC of the chapter is on the right.

[image]

There have been some efforts being made to [add a picture next to the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31518/adding-a-per-chapter-image-along-with-group-of-entries-in-toc) or to use [minipages and TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/mini-table-of-contents-inside-tikz-node-on-chapter-start-page).

However, is it possible to recreate this layout with `minitoc` (or similar alternatives) and `TikZ`?

My attempts so far have not been that great, here is a MWE:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor, tikz, lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\definecolor{azure}{HTML}{105F74}
\usepackage[german]{minitoc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\setlength{\mtcskipamount}{\bigskipamount}
\mtcsetfont{minitoc}{section}{\small\rmfamily\upshape}
\mtifont{\huge\color{azure}}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\faketableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
{\huge\sffamily\textcolor{azure}{Learning goals}}
\flushleft
\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{azure}\theenumi.]
\item  First Goal
\item  Second goal
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\nomtcrule\minitoc
\end{minipage}
\section{Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection One}
\section{Section Two}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}
\end{document}
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

In particular, (at least) the following points are missing:

- alignment of Learning Goals to "Inhaltsangabe"
- indent of TOC
- colored seperation line

How can this (and maybe some more improvements) be done?

**EDIT**: I included `\usepackage{enumitem}` to make the enumeration point in the desired color.

Comment: Just added a MWE, thank you!

Comment: The default is to align the centers of minpages.  OTOH, [t] doesn't quite work either, due to the differences between enumerate and mintoc.

Comment: Ah, nice to know! So do you have any other suggestion on how to align these two columns? Multicol? Tikz matrices?

Comment: @Aericura, have succeded replicating the rest of the Layout? I need help with the headers.

Comment: @Mauramz no, I aborted the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{azure}{HTML}{105F74}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multicol}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{.3pt}
  \def\columnseprulecolor{\color{azure}}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
  \setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}
  \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}
  \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{\cftsecindent}
  \addtolength{\cftsubsecindent}{\cftsecnumwidth}
  \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3em}
  \setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{\cftsubsecindent}
  \addtolength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{\cftsubsecnumwidth}
\usepackage[german]{minitoc}
  \mtcsettitle{minitoc}{}
  \mtcsetrules{minitoc}{off}
  \setlength{\mtcindent}{0em}

\begin{document}
  \dominitoc
  \faketableofcontents

  \chapter{Chapter One}
    \begin{multicols}{2}

      \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      \textcolor{azure}{\large\bfseries Learning goals}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\color{azure}\theenumi.]
          \item  First Goal
          \item  Second goal
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{minipage}

      \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      \textcolor{azure}{\large\bfseries Inhaltsangabe}
        \minitoc
      \end{minipage}

    \end{multicols}

  \section{Section One}
    \subsection{Subsection One}
  \section{Section Two}
  \section{Section Three}
  \section{Section Four}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Colud you do vertical alignment between minitoc and learning goals?

Comment: @MamounMohammed – Sure. I'd suggest you ask a new question...